# How to filter for just one customer with yajra datatables

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

I have a customers table with each record linking to a customer contact:

http://localhost/untdchem/public/home/customers/contacts/1809

When I click on the above link, I want to display all the contacts for customer 1809 only in a datatable. I am trying to pass the customer ID somehow so I can filter for that customer only. I can fill the table with all the contacts but i want to just load for that customer.

Routes:

```
 //Customer Contacts
        Route::get('home/customers/contacts', ['as' => 'customers.contacts', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@index']);
        Route::get('home/customers/contacts/data', ['as' => 'customers.contacts.data', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@anyData']);
```

In my controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        // GET request to index
        return view('pages.customer_contacts.index');
    }

 public function anyData()
    {


    $contacts = customer_contact::select(['CustContactFName','CustContactLName','CustContactCountryCode','CustContactExtension','CustContactPhone','CustContactEmail','CustContactType']);
    return Datatables::of($contacts)->make(true);     
    }
```

In my view:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#customer-contacts-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,

        ajax: '{!! route('customers.contacts.data') !!}',

        columns: [
            { data: 'CustContactFName', name: 'CustContactFName'},
            { data: 'CustContactLName', name: 'CustContactLName'},
            { data: 'CustContactCountryCode', name: 'CustContactCountryCode'},
            { data: 'CustContactExtension', name: 'CustContactExtension'},
            { data: 'CustContactPhone', name: 'CustContactPhone'},
            { data: 'CustContactEmail', name: 'CustContactEmail'},
            { data: 'CustContactType', name: 'CustContactType'}
            //{ data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
        order: [[0, "desc" ]]
    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution below:

```
public function index($CustID = null, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $contacts = customer_contact::select(['CustContactFName','CustContactLName','CustContactCountryCode','CustContactExtension','CustContactPhone','CustContactEmail','CustContactType']);
        if ($CustID) {
            $contacts->where('CustID', $CustID);
        }

        //dd($contacts);

        return Datatables::of($contacts)
         ->addColumn('action', function ($contacts) {

                $links="";
                $links.='<a href="'.url('home/customers/contacts/edit', [$contacts->CustID]).'">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
                $links.='<a class="delete" href="'.url('home/customers/contacts/delete', [$contacts->CustID]).'">Delete</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
                return $links;

            })->make(true);     
    }

    return view('pages.customer_contacts.index', compact('CustID'));
}


<script>
$(function() {
    $('#customer-contacts-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,

        ajax: '{!! route('customers.contacts', $CustID) !!}',

        columns: [
            { data: 'CustContactFName', name: 'CustContactFName'},
            { data: 'CustContactLName', name: 'CustContactLName'},
            { data: 'CustContactCountryCode', name: 'CustContactCountryCode'},
            { data: 'CustContactExtension', name: 'CustContactExtension'},
            { data: 'CustContactPhone', name: 'CustContactPhone'},
            { data: 'CustContactEmail', name: 'CustContactEmail'},
            { data: 'CustContactType', name: 'CustContactType'},
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
        order: [[0, "desc" ]]
    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Routes

```
Route::get('home/customers/contacts/{id}', ['as' => 'customers.contacts', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@index']);
Route::get('home/customers/contacts/data/{id}', ['as' => 'customers.contacts.data', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@anyData']);
```

#### Controller

I am assuming there is `CustId` field that identifies which customer the contact record is assigned to. If your structure is different, adjust accordingly.

```
public function index($id) {
    // GET request to index
    return view('pages.customer_contacts.index', compact('id'));
}

public function anyData($id){    
   $contacts = customer_contact::select([
         'CustContactFName',
         'CustContactLName',
         'CustContactCountryCode',
         'CustContactExtension',
         'CustContactPhone',
         'CustContactEmail',
         'CustContactType'
      ])
      ->where('CustId', '=', $id);

   return Datatables::of($contacts)->make(true);     
}
```

#### JavaScript

Update the line with `ajax` option:

```
ajax: '{!! route('customers.contacts.data', ['id' => $id]) !!}',
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that solution before and got the following error: Missing required parameters for [Route: customers.contacts.data] [URI: home/customers/contacts/data/{id}]. (View: C:\wamp\www\untdchem\resources\views\pages\customer_contacts\index.blade.php)   Note: My routes are:Route::get('home/customers/contacts/{id}', ['as' => 'customers.contacts', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@index']);
 Route::get('home/customers/contacts/data/{id}', ['as' => 'customers.contacts.data', 'uses' => 'CustomerContactsController@anyData']);

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the same error. Missing required parameters for [Route: customers.contacts.data] [URI: home/customers/contacts/data/{id}]. (View: C:\wamp\www\untdchem\resources\views\pages\customer_contacts\index.blade.php). When I type in the direct link into the browser: http://localhost/untdchem/public/home/customers/contacts/data/1809 . I get the json string with all the data. I tried replacing the ajax call with: ajax: 'http://localhost/untdchem/public/home/customers/contacts/data/1809', and still get the same error. I did a dd($id) in the view and it is ok.

Comment: @user2197774, please make sure that you use the updated code in my answer. Are you visiting `/home/customers/contacts/1809` to see the list of contacts?

Comment: That is correct, I used that url, and that is when the error is thrown. See above comments I just edited. Thanks

Comment: @user2197774, If you view the source code for the page `/home/customers/contacts/1809` do you see `ajax: '/untdchem/public/home/customers/contacts/data/1809'`? Otherwise make sure you have updated the routes.php, controller and the view as in my answer. Also make sure that you have `CustId` column and the logic is correct.

Comment: I tried to check the source before but the page, /home/customers/contacts/1809 is the one that is throwing the above error, so i cannot see the original source code.

Comment: @user2197774, I think I know where the problem is, it should be `route('customers.contacts.data', ['id' => $id])` instead. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, no that didn't work. This should work, ajax: 'http://localhost/untdchem/public/home/customers/contacts/data/1809' in theory but it doesn't. Thanks for your help anyhow.